# XAMPP: MySQL won't start Error

Tags: server, mysql, xampp

I can't figure out why MySQL Database on XAMPP won't run.

```
opt/lampp/bin/mysql.server: 260: kill: No such process
```

I get this message in terminal and localhost:/phpmyadmin shows an error.

I've already tried to stop mysql daemons by `service stop mysql`. However this hasn't changed anything.

Do you have any solutions?
Is that because of some permission problems?
Are there any corrupted files?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem by uninstalling all packages of PHP and MySQL. I believe that was especially because of the PHP Daemons. Everything works fine after that.